# XCode как передвигать элементы по экрану программно

Tags: swift, xcode, анимация, view

У меня есть view, который называеться informationView, в нём есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую, informationView должен плавно "уплывать" под сцену и также при определённых условиях должен "выплывать". Я не знаю как можно сделать это даже без плавности. Может можно изменять значение уже существующего constraint, то проблемма с перемещением informationView решаеться, но проблемма с плавностью остаеться, тоже самое если можно изменить координату Y этого view напрямую, но я не нашёл способа как сделать это. а плавность этого перехода для меня вообще загадка

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e25Vp.jpg

вот как это выглядит на моем андроид приложении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плавное перемещение делается с помощью анимации. Ряд свойств у вью анимируется, в том числе констрейнты. Например через UIView.animate()

Answer (score 0):

В iOS на данный момент очень популярно использование AutoLayout. Расположение объектов расчитывается от примененных на него constraint.

Вы можете перетащить outlet констрейнта объекта в ваш класс и изменять в течении времени

```
self.myConstaint.constant = 0

UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { 
    self.myConstraint.constant = 100 
})
```